# Driving a car in the UK which registered to a family member in another EU country

Tags: united-kingdom, eu, car

As a european visiting the UK, am I allowed to drive a car registered to a family member in another EU country or does the car have to be registered to me?

I have found information on the links below, but they do not give me any clarity on this matter:

- [Car registration in another EU country](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/vehicles/registration/taxes/index_en.htm),
- <del>http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/vehicles/registration/taxes/united-kingdom/index_en.htm</del>: dead link (verified on 26.12.2020) but see [Registration of cars and motorised vehicles in the EU - Your Europe](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/vehicles/registration/index_en.htm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [Hughes Guides](http://www.hughesguides.com/foreignvehicles.pdf), which publishes UK technical traffic & criminal legal guides:

> **Foreign Vehicles in the UK**
>   *by K. Mark Hughes*
>
> Foreign registered vehicles from any country may be brought into and used in the UK on a temporary basis by persons who are not resident here for up to 6 months at a time, extensions to this period can be arranged. This concession, negotiated under Chapter III of the Convention on Road Traffic at Vienna on 8th November 1968, permits non-residents, such as tourists, people visiting businesses, friends or family etc. to use their vehicle on UK Roads without the need to re-register it here providing certain conditions are complied with:
>
> - the vehicle's registration certificate is carried by the driver, and, if the vehicles is not registered in the name of an occupant of the vehicle, proof of the driver's right to be in possession of the vehicle must be produced,
> - the registration number is displayed at the front and rear of the vehicles (motorcycles rear only),
> - registration numbers must be displayed in Latin characters and Arabic numerals,
> - a distinguishing sign of the country of registration is displayed on the rear of the vehicle. This sign may be incorporated into the registration plate or placed separately,
> - the vehicle must be legal for road use in the country of registration.
>
> **It is the keeper's responsibility to show they are allowed to use the vehicle in the UK without registering and taxing it.**